# Onenote API (REST) - PATCH append - "must include a 'commands'" error when Commands is already supplied (?!)

Tags: api, rest, patch, onenote

Note: I'm pretty sure nothing's wrong with the PATCH query, I had it working before with 'Content-type':'application/json' and a constructed json file:

```
[
  {
  'target':'|TARGET_ID|',
  'action':'append',
  'content':'|HTML|'
  }  
]
```

For the purposes of this, the header supplied (authentication bearer is correct and will be omitted)

```
'Content-type':'multipart/form-data; Boundary=sectionboundary'
```

(note: Boundary=sectionboundary is in the same line)

Attempting to pass the following body as a PATCH to
    https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/pages/|GUID|/content
 returns a 
     "code":"20124","message":"A multi-part PATCH request must include a 'commands' part containing the PATCH action JSON structure." :

```
--sectionboundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Commands"
Content-Type: application/json
[
  {
  'target':'|TARGET_ID|',
  'action':'append',
  'content':'|HTML|'
  }  
]

--sectionboundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image-part-name"
Content-Type: image/png

|BINARY_IMAGE_DATA|

--sectionboundary--
```

As you can see, there's a Commands section already. Using smallcaps 'commands' doesn't help, and the correct syntax should be "Commands" as per the OneNote Dev Center documentation.

PS: |TARGET_ID| |HTML| |GUID| and |BINARY_DATA| are replaced with the correct content at runtime. Due to privacy constraints, the fact that you may use a different schema than I do, and how long |BINARY_IMAGE_DATA| actually is, I will not show the actual input unless required to solve the problem.

Would like to know if I missed anything - thanks in advance.

PPS: Yes, I realize i've omitted the img tag inside |HTML| somewhere. It shouldn't have anything to do with code 20124, and if I got it wrong should return another thing entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on investigating the request information you shared, I can confirm that the PATCH request referenced as part of the correlation you provided does not match your posted header information. 
The correlated PATCH request shows up as a multi-part request with only a single part that has Media Type "TEXT/HTML" and not "Application/JSON". Can you please check and confirm your request content ?
Let us continue to discuss this on email. If you still face issues calling the API, please write to me at machandw@microsoft.com

Regards,
Manoj

Comment: Hi, this is interesting. The entire structure was sent as a Text body of the HTTP request - It's UTF8 encoded. Were it JSON I would have instead used a hash table. I'll check the inputs again - thanks for your help, because without it, I wouldn't know what's wrong on my end.

Comment: Hi, as it turns out, I had indeed posted by mistake a Text/HTML into the request text. It was my default template. Thanks for the help again.