# OneNote API (REST) - <div> tags seeem to be stripped during PATCH

Tags: html, api, get, patch, onenote

Note: using the same PATCH request as defined in [Onenote API (REST) - PATCH append - "must include a 'commands'" error when Commands is already supplied (?!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017705/onenote-api-rest-patch-append-must-include-a-commands-error-when-comma)

Each PATCH request is an append operation, and uses the following layout supplied to |HTML| in my code:

```
<div>
  <h1>Hardcoded_Name_ForNow</h1>
  <h3>4.345054</h3>
  <p>sdfsdfsdf</p>
  <img src="name:image-part-name" alt="New binary image" />
</div>
```

However, when I GET the content of the page (ref: https://jsapi.apiary.io/apis/onenote/reference/get-pages/v10pagesid/get.html?console=1), it turns out like this:

```
(HEADER OMITTED)
<body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
  <div style="width:624px">
    <h1 style="font-size:16pt;color:#1e4e79;margin-top:11pt;margin-bottom:11pt">Hardcoded_Name_ForNow</h1>
    <h3 style="font-size:12pt;color:#5b9bd5;margin-top:11pt;margin-bottom:11pt">47.77527</h3>
    <p>TEST</p>
    <img alt="New binary image" width="624" height="353" src="https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/resources/0-60a8d03c70a04372ad60cabb8191f86d!1-6C3CB48828A4FCE7!185/$value" data-src-type="image/png" data-fullres-src="https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/resources/0-60a8d03c70a04372ad60cabb8191f86d!1-6C3CB48828A4FCE7!185/$value" data-fullres-src-type="image/png" />
    <h1 style="font-size:16pt;color:#1e4e79;margin-top:11pt;margin-bottom:11pt">Hardcoded_Name_ForNow</h1>
    <h3 style="font-size:12pt;color:#5b9bd5;margin-top:11pt;margin-bottom:11pt">41.16911</h3>
    <p>ewqeqweqweqew</p>
    <img alt="New binary image" width="624" height="353" src="https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/resources/0-9d9ab7935d16464eb826e70dd7fdb3ef!1-6C3CB48828A4FCE7!185/$value" data-src-type="image/png" data-fullres-src="https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/resources/0-9d9ab7935d16464eb826e70dd7fdb3ef!1-6C3CB48828A4FCE7!185/$value" data-fullres-src-type="image/png" />

    ...

  </div>
</body>
```

I know that if I didn't supply a specific target ID, the PATCH request will target the topmost . However, I expected the PATCH request to throw in the layout wholesale without stripping the  encapsulator.

Currently working around it by assuming h1, h3, p, img will always be in order, but this is harder to maintain if the tag order changes or new tags are added.

Enabling div id attributes doesn't help, the  are simply not there in the first place.

Comment: I've tried many combinations of adding outer divs and these still get stripped away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't really have a way to store arbitrary containers in OneNote, so we sort of do our best to resynthesize them on demand.  Unless they have some meaningful distinguishing data, individual ones can melt away, as you are seeing.  Our aim it to get presentation content in and out of the surface rather than to be a high fidelity HTML store.

So that said, if you add a data-id="UniqueFoo" attribute to your , we treat it as semantically meaningful, so we do extra work to reproduce those semantics.   The HTML may not be *exactly* the same, but we should produce the semantic equivalent as far as containment goes, which will likely in this simple case mean your  is preserved as you'd expect.

You could use a guid or some such as the data-id attribute for an easy unique value if there's nothing unique in your app that these divs represent.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if throwing an ID in the encapsulating div tags work. If they don't, I have a backup plan that involves putting the ID inside the first h1, and I'll have to hardcode a CSS style to keep the whole thing from overlapping the page title.

Comment: That should be "data-id" rather than "id"